# How to listen for UIReturnKeyType.Next with Swift iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When the user presses next on the keypad I want to move from the current UITextField to the next UITextField, the UIReturnKeyType is set to UIReturnKeyType.Next

Here is how I have the UITextField set up.

```
username.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next
username.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
username.placeholder = "Username"
username.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
uUsername.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
username.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
username.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 14)
username.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None
username.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to configure the UITextFieldDelegate method `textFieldShouldReturn:`. From within this method, you can check which text field is returning and reassign first responder status accordingly. Of course this mean you'll have to assign your class as the delegate of the text fields.

Example:

```
class MyClass: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func setup() { // meaningless method name
        textField1.delegate = self
        textField2.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if (textField === textField1) {
            textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else if (textField === textField2) {
            textField2.resignFirstResponder()
        } else {
            // etc
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: What does
     textField1.delegate = self
 do?

Comment: @StephenFox `delegate` is a property on each UITextField. In order for the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method to be called, that property must be assigned to the same class that contains the method. (It tells the text field who implements its delegate methods) You can set this property in the same place as the other properties like backgroundColor, placeholder, etc..

Comment: So basically I am telling the compiler that textField1 is delegated by the current class I am in?

Comment: @StephenFox Correct. You have to make sure that you specify that the class conforms to the protocol as well (the `MyClass: UITextFieldDelegate` part)

Comment: What does the === actually mean in the if statement? I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @StephenFox It compares the reference instead of the values. It's making sure that `textField` is the exact same object as `textField1`.

Comment: FYI, Swift has changed since this answer, so you now should remove the ! after UITextField in the function signature.

Comment: Something more scalable if your form is large or prone to updating...

`code`
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        if let nextTextField = self.view.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1){
            nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
`code`

Answer (score 5):

Follow the steps given below:

1) You will be needing to set the tags in the incremental sequence of the textfields in xib/Storyboard or in code.

2) Set the delegate for each of the textfields.

3) Then paste the following code in your view controller to have the desired effect:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    let nextTag: Int = textField.tag + 1

    let nextResponder: UIResponder? = textField.superview?.superview?.viewWithTag(nextTag)

    if let nextR = nextResponder
    {
        // Found next responder, so set it.
        nextR.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else
    {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    return false
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 2):

If you have two textfield :
- textField1
- textField2

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

    textField1.resignFirstResponder()
    textField2.becomeFirstResponder()

    return true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate    //set delegate to class

@IBOutlet var txtValue: UITextField    //create a textfield variable

override func viewDidLoad() { 
super.viewDidLoad() 
txtValue.delegate = self //set delegate to textfile 
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   //delegate method
return true
}
```